# New Release RC0 , Issue with this.context.httpClient.get method

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

Till drop 6 i was able to get user properties using Rest call method as below.

*public getUserProperties(): Promise {
    return this.context.httpClient.get(
      `${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties`)
      .then((response: Response) => {
        return response.json();
      });
  }*

now with new Release RC0, this.context.httpClient.get method is asking for one Extra Parameter which is called configuration of Type "HttpClientConfiguration".
[here](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/reference/spdx/sp-http/get-httpclient) i found the method defintion on web. I am not sure what paramter need to pass for this, as description it said "normally this should be the latest version number from HttpClientConfigurations". i would like to know what is the latest version of HttpClientConfigurations.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry to disturb i got the Answer from Release Notes "Update your webpart" section. https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Release-Notes-RC0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of breaking changes introduced in RCO:

Use it as below:

```
import {
  SPHttpClient
} from '@microsoft/sp-http'

private _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {
  return this.context.spHttpClient.get(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + '/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties', SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
    .then((response: Response) => {
      return response.json();
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this imply that SPFx's spHttpClient does **not** return a JSON structure by default??

Comment: No, JSON is the default, as is ODataV4, etc.  Those configurations are all captured in the V1 configuration.  The full V1 configuration is

   * consoleLogging = true;

   * jsonRequest = true;

   * jsonResponse = true;

   * defaultSameOriginCredentials = true;

   * defaultODataVersion = ODataVersion.v4;

   * requestDigest = true

The goal with the configuration is to be able to change defaults without breaking existing code, by combining those defaults into configurations.

Comment: my this.context.spHttpClient is undefined